# RabbitMQ workers with unique key

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm thinking of using RabbitMQ for a new project (with little own RabbitMQ experience) to solve the following problem:

Upon an event, a long running computation has to be performed. The "work queue" pattern as described in https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html seems to be perfect, but I want an additional twist: I want no two jobs with the same routing key (or some parts of the payload or metadata, however to implement that) running on the workers at the same time. In other words: when one worker is processing job XY, and another job XY is queued, the message XY must not be delivered to a new idle worker until the running worker has completed the job.

What would be the best strategy to implement that? The only real solution I came up with was that when a worker gets a job, it has to check with all other workers if they are currently processing a similar job, and if so, reject the message (for requeueing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your architecture there are two approaches to your problem.

1. The consumers share a cache of tasks under process and if a job of the same type shows up, they [reject](https://www.rabbitmq.com/nack.html) or requeue it.

   This requires a shared cache to be maintained and a bit of logic on the consumers side.

   The side effect is that duplicated jobs will keep returning to the consumers in case of rejection while in case of requeueing they will be processed with unpredictable delay (depending on how big the queue is).
2. You use the [deduplication plugin](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication#queue-level-deduplication) on the queue.

   You won't need any additional cache, only a few lines of code on the publisher side.

   The downside of this approach is that duplicated messages will be dropped. If you want them to be delivered, you will need to instruct the publisher to retry in case of a [negative acknowledgment on the publisher](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#publisher-confirms).

Comment: Thank you. The first option is what I also came up with as solution, I'm just wondering if there's nothing simpler/more supported by RabbitMQ directly. The second option doesn't really solve my problem, as that plug in only looks at messages in the queue, not including tasks that are already being processed.

Comment: The plugins works for your use case if you use the [message acknowledgment](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) pattern. The typical usage pattern with RabbitMQ is: fetch a message -- process it -- acknowledge it. The dedup plugin will consider a message in the queue until the consumer does not acknowledge it.

Comment: So do I understand you correctly, that until the consumer ACKs a message, the plugin takes that message into account when deduplicating? And that the producer is notified (with a negative ack), when the plugin can't queue a message because of deduplication? That would indeed be of great help for my problem. Both should be documented in the plugins readme though. :-)

Comment: It is not a feature of the plugin but rather the way RabbitMQ works. A message is considered belonging to a queue until it is not acknowledged. Publishing confirmation is sent when a message has been published on all the queues. You can read more about consumer acknowledgment and publish confirmation in the [official documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html).

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a shot